# How Can I Debug A Bios Better

Tags: ida, debugging, gdb, bios

I am trying to reverse engineer a firmkit in a bios, but in general I would like to know how can I debug a bios better.

I found a way to attach IDA to a vmware instance usign a GDB session [GDB Debugging With VMware](https://cyberview.wordpress.com/2010/09/16/debugging-bios-under-vmware-using-idas-gdb-debugger/), but it seems like I am always racing to against the bios and boot up of the VM. I am wanting to have it stop in a place that I can follow and make sense of.

In general, What are some better practices when debugging a bios? Is IDA a decent debugger for this task? Is there something more meant for this task? Any other ideas are welcome also, I am really wanting to focus on reversing malware that is written to the bios.

Thanks!

Comment: UEFI firmware is relatively easy to reverse engineer as most of the protocols are well documented and most implementations are based on the Tianocore reference implementation.   A traditional BIOS is harder to reverse engineer as documentation is not readily available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try running your BIOS in QEMU. QEMU's `-S` option will pause boot until a debugger (gdb) is attached. IDA's debugger apparently works fine with QEMU, according to this article: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/tutorials/debugging_gdb_qemu.pdf

Comment: Same idea, I managed to use VMware 7 and it worked fine.